unable to write / scribble in WPS Office Writer write using my Wacom Pen Tablet in Windows
I am unable to write/ scribble in WPS Office Writer using my Pen Tablet under the Draw features tab. I can although do the same when I scribble using my laptop touchpad. I am currently using the version WPS - Release Version v12.2.0.16909-release. I had the same issue earlier when I installed WPS Office 2019.
The version of my Pen Tablet is One by Wacom CTL-672.
I will really be grateful if someone could help me with this problem. I am a tutor so I need to correct the student's mistake using the Pen tablet and this feature is crucial to me.
